# Decoding with SUBSTRING and INSTRING?

Tags: oracle

I have a table which has city column having few records with state values as well-separated by comma.
There are other records without, as well. I want to take the state values for those present into a separate field called `state`.
How to do that? I tried the code below and it is saying "missing right parenthesis":

```
SELECT  DECODE(ORA_CITY,
                 INSTR(ORA_CITY,',') > 0, 
                   SUBSTR(ORA_CITY, INSTR(ORA_CITY, ','), LENGTH(ORA_CITY) ) ,
                   NULL) AS STATE 
from ADDRESS
```

Comment: It would help to show an example or two of "before" and "after" data.  Is the state that is embedded in the city the standard 2-character code?

Comment: `SELECT regexp_substr(ORA_CITY, ',(.*)$', 1, 1, '', 1) AS STATE from ADDRESS`

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if you still need it but use CASE:

```
SELECT CASE
     WHEN INSTR(ORA_CITY, '5') > 0 THEN
       SUBSTR(ORA_CITY, INSTR(ORA_CITY, '5'), LENGTH(ORA_CITY))
     ELSE
       NULL
   END STATE 
  FROM ADDRESS
```

Answer (score 1):

Clearly you have not understood decode syntax.

Try the following:

```
SELECT  DECODE(INSTR(ORA_CITY,','), 
               0,
               NULL,
               SUBSTR(ORA_CITY, INSTR(ORA_CITY, ','), LENGTH(ORA_CITY) )) AS STATE 
FROM ADDRESS
```

The correct syntax is:

> DECODE( expression , search , result [, search , result]... [,
>   default] ), where
>
> expression is the value to compare.
>
> search is the value that is compared against expression.
>
> result is the value returned, if expression is equal to search.
>
> default is optional. If no matches are found, the DECODE function will
>   return default. If default is omitted, then the DECODE function will
>   return null (if no matches are found).

Examples [here](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/instr.php) and [here](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/decode.php)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT REGEX_REPLACE(ORA_CITY, '.*, *', '') AS STATE
FROM ADDRESS
WHERE ORA_CITY LIKE '%,%'
```

This uses regular expression to replace all upto the comma, and then maybe spaces with nothing. A WHERE included.